# Seekbar showing only progress color and not background color

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I am using a custom seekbar drawable and set its progress to 50 in my xml. It shows perfectly fine in Android Studio Preview, but in device, the background color is same as the progress color. I am using Nexus 5 with Android version: 6.0.1. Here are the codes and screenshots:

**Seekbar:**

```
 <SeekBar
     android:id="@+id/seekbar"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@id/ivRepeat"
     android:indeterminate="false"
     android:maxHeight="2dp"
     android:minHeight="2dp"
     android:progress="50"
     android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_drawable"
     android:thumbTint="@color/seekColor" />
```

**progress_drawable.xml:**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="5dip" />
            <solid android:color="#F7CCBD" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="5dip" />
                <solid android:color="@color/seekColor" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**seekColor value:** #87DED5

**How it shows in Android studio Preview:**
[image]

**How it shows in my device:**
[image]

Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: add an item with id `@android:id/secondaryProgress` with the same content of `@android:id/progress` and run it again

Comment: @Blackbelt I did it before, same issue. So, I tried removing it. Again, same issue.

Comment: If you use "Instant run", try switching it off and rebuilding the project.

Comment: @VeaceslavGaidarji Nope, I am not using instant run.

Comment: could you try without `android:thumbTint="@color/seekColor"` ?

Comment: @Blackbelt tried that too, same issue.

Comment: @Blackbelt I used this drawable before: http://pastie.org/pastes/10910587/text. The issue was still same.

Comment: @berserk I went through your code, it works fine, did you define color in appropriate folder?

Comment: @Silwester yes. I put <color name="seekColor">#87DED5</color> in colors.xml inside values folder.

Comment: do you try changing `android:thumbTintMode`? Could you test it on a different device?

Comment: Sorry guys. I had a line in my java file which was doing this. 
        seekbar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(
                getResources().getColor(R.color.seekColor), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)); I was using this to change the color before, but was unable to change its thickness, so I changed to custom drawable. But forgot to delete this line. I feel dumb...

Comment: @berserk, then you should probably delete the thread, since it is hardly gonna help somebody

Comment: @Blackbelt right, thanks.

Comment: @Blackbelt I can't delete it because it got answers. My flag for deletion was declined also.

Answer (score 7):

Here,
Code have no issue once clear project.

If still issue then try below code snippet.

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:id="@android:id/background"> <!--background of seekbar--> 
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="5dip" />
                <solid android:color="#F7CCBD" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item android:id="@android:id/progress"> <!--progress color-->
            <clip>
                <shape>
                    <corners android:radius="5dip" />
                    <solid android:color="#87DED5" />
                </shape>
            </clip>
        </item>
        <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"> <!--secondaryProgress color-->
            <clip>
                <shape>
                    <corners android:radius="5dip" />
                    <solid android:color="#F7CCBD" />
                </shape>
            </clip>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

Customize seekbar to change the color of the seekbar progress, progress background and color of the thumb.

Below is the customized seekbar class.

```
package com.customseekbar;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.ColorStateList;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.NinePatchDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.ScaleDrawable;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.IntRange;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

import com.customseekbar.R;

import java.util.concurrent.Callable;


public class CustomSeekBar extends SeekBar implements View.OnTouchListener {

private static final String TAG = "CustomSeekbar";
private int mActualBackgroundColor;

/***
 * Thumb and Progress colors
 */
int mThumbColor, mProgressColor, mProgressBackgroundColor;

/***
 * Thumb drawable
 */
Drawable mThumb;
/***
 * States for Lollipop ColorStateList
 */
int[][] states = new int[][]{
        new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // enabled
        new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed},  // pressed
        new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // disabled
        new int[]{} //everything else
};

/***
 * Default colors to be black for Thumb ColorStateList
 */
int[] colorsThumb = new int[]{
        Color.BLACK,
        Color.BLACK,
        Color.LTGRAY,
        Color.BLACK
};

/***
 * Default colors to be black for Progress ColorStateList
 */
int[] colorsProgress = new int[]{
        Color.BLACK,
        Color.BLACK,
        Color.LTGRAY,
        Color.BLACK
};

/***
 * Default colors to be black for Progress ColorStateList
 */
int[] colorsProgressBackground = new int[]{
        Color.BLACK,
        Color.BLACK,
        Color.LTGRAY,
        Color.BLACK

};

/***
 * ColorStateList objects
 */
ColorStateList mColorStateListThumb, mColorStateListProgress, mColorStateListProgressBackground;

/***
 * Used for APIs below 21 to determine height of the seekBar as well as the new thumb drawable
 */
private int mOriginalThumbHeight;
private int mThumbAlpha = 255;
private boolean mIsEnabled = true;

/***
 * Updates the thumbColor dynamically
 *
 * @param thumbColor Color representing thumb drawable
 */
public void setThumbColor(final int thumbColor) {
    mThumbColor = thumbColor;
    if (lollipopAndAbove()) {
        setupThumbColorLollipop();
    } else {
        gradientDrawable.setColor(mIsEnabled ? thumbColor : Color.LTGRAY);
    }
    invalidate();
    requestLayout();
}

/***
 * Method called for APIs 21 and above to setup thumb Color
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private void setupThumbColorLollipop() {
    if (lollipopAndAbove()) {
        colorsThumb[0] = mThumbColor;
        colorsThumb[1] = mThumbColor;
        colorsThumb[2] = Color.LTGRAY;
        mColorStateListThumb = new ColorStateList(states, colorsThumb);
        setThumbTintList(mColorStateListThumb);
    } else {

    }
}

/***
 * Updates the progressColor dynamically
 *
 * @param progressColor Color representing progress drawable
 */
public void setProgressColor(final int progressColor) {
    mProgressColor = progressColor;
    if (lollipopAndAbove()) {
        setupProgressColorLollipop();
    } else {
        setupProgressColor();
    }

    invalidate();
    requestLayout();
}

/***
 * Checks if the device is running API greater than 21
 *
 * @return true if lollipop and above
 */
private boolean lollipopAndAbove() {
    return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP;
}

/***
 * Method called from APIs below 21 to setup Progress Color
 */
private void setupProgressColor() {
    try {
        //load up the drawable and apply color
        LayerDrawable ld = (LayerDrawable) getProgressDrawable();
        ScaleDrawable shape = (ScaleDrawable) (ld.findDrawableByLayerId(android.R.id.progress));
        shape.setColorFilter(mProgressColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

        //set the background to transparent
        NinePatchDrawable ninePatchDrawable = (NinePatchDrawable) (ld.findDrawableByLayerId(android.R.id.background));
        ninePatchDrawable.setColorFilter(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        //TODO: Handle exception
    }
}

/***
 * Method called from APIs >= 21 to setup Progress Color
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private void setupProgressColorLollipop() {
    colorsProgress[0] = mProgressColor;
    colorsProgress[1] = mProgressColor;
    mColorStateListProgress = new ColorStateList(states, colorsProgress);
    setProgressTintList(mColorStateListProgress);
}

/***
 * Updates the progressBackgroundColor dynamically
 *
 * @param progressBackgroundColor Color representing progress drawable
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
public void setProgressBackgroundColor(final int progressBackgroundColor) {
    mProgressBackgroundColor = progressBackgroundColor;
    if (lollipopAndAbove()) {
        setupProgressBackgroundLollipop();
    } else {
        setupProgressBackground();
    }
    invalidate();
    requestLayout();
}

/***
 * Method called from APIs 21 and above to setup the Progress-background-line Color
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private void setupProgressBackgroundLollipop() {
    colorsProgressBackground[0] = mProgressBackgroundColor;
    colorsProgressBackground[1] = mProgressBackgroundColor;
    mColorStateListProgressBackground = new ColorStateList(states, colorsProgressBackground);
    setProgressBackgroundTintList(mColorStateListProgressBackground);
}

/***
 * Method called from APIs below 21 to setup the Progress-background-line Color
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
private void setupProgressBackground() {
    //load up the drawable and apply color
    SeekbarBackgroundDrawable seekBarBackgroundDrawable = new SeekbarBackgroundDrawable(getContext(),
            mProgressBackgroundColor, mActualBackgroundColor, getPaddingLeft(), getPaddingRight());
    if (belowJellybean())
        setBackgroundDrawable(seekBarBackgroundDrawable);
    else
        setBackground(seekBarBackgroundDrawable);
}

/***
 * Constructor for creating CustomSeekbar through code
 *
 * @param context Context object
 */
public SeekBar(final Context context) {
    super(context);
}

GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = new GradientDrawable();

/***
 * Constructor for creating CustomSeekbar through XML
 *
 * @param context Context Object
 * @param attrs   Attributes passed through XML
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public CustomSeekBar(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    TypedArray a = context.getTheme()
            .obtainStyledAttributes(
                    attrs,
                    R.styleable.SeekBarCompat,
                    0, 0);
    int array[] = {android.R.attr.background, android.R.attr.enabled};
    TypedArray b = context.getTheme()
            .obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, array, 0, 0);
    try {
        mThumbColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.SeekBarCompat_thumbColor, getPrimaryColorFromSelectedTheme(context));
        mProgressColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.SeekBarCompat_progressColor, getPrimaryColorFromSelectedTheme(context));
        mProgressBackgroundColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.SeekBarCompat_progressBackgroundColor, Color.BLACK);
        mThumbAlpha = (int) (a.getFloat(R.styleable.SeekBarCompat_thumbAlpha, 1) * 255);
        mActualBackgroundColor = b.getColor(0, Color.TRANSPARENT);
        mIsEnabled = b.getBoolean(1, true);
        if (lollipopAndAbove()) {
            setSplitTrack(false);
            setupThumbColorLollipop();
            setupProgressColorLollipop();
            setupProgressBackgroundLollipop();
            getThumb().setAlpha(mThumbAlpha);
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "CustomSeekbar isEnabled? " + mIsEnabled);
            setupProgressColor();
            setOnTouchListener(this);
            gradientDrawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.OVAL);
            gradientDrawable.setSize(50, 50);
            gradientDrawable.setColor(mIsEnabled ? mThumbColor : Color.LTGRAY);
            triggerMethodOnceViewIsDisplayed(this, new Callable<Void>() {
                @Override
                public Void call() throws Exception {
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = getLayoutParams();
                    mOriginalThumbHeight = mThumb.getIntrinsicHeight();
                    gradientDrawable.setSize(mOriginalThumbHeight / 3, mOriginalThumbHeight / 3);
                    gradientDrawable.setAlpha(mThumbAlpha);
                    setThumb(gradientDrawable);
                    if (layoutParams.height < mOriginalThumbHeight)
                        layoutParams.height = mOriginalThumbHeight;
                    setupProgressBackground();
                    return null;
                }
            });
        }
    } finally {
        a.recycle();
        b.recycle();
    }
}

private boolean belowJellybean() {
    return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16;
}

/***
 * Gets the Primary Color from theme
 *
 * @param context Context Object
 * @return Primary Color
 */
public static int getPrimaryColorFromSelectedTheme(Context context) {
    int[] attrs = {R.attr.colorPrimary, R.attr.colorPrimaryDark};
    TypedArray ta = context.getTheme()
            .obtainStyledAttributes(attrs);
    int primaryColor = ta.getColor(0, Color.BLACK); //1 index for primaryColorDark
    //default value for primaryColor is set to black if primaryColor not found
    ta.recycle();
    return primaryColor;
}

/***
 * Utility method for ViewTreeObserver
 *
 * @param view   View object
 * @param method Method to be called once View is displayed
 */
public static void triggerMethodOnceViewIsDisplayed(final View view, final Callable<Void> method) {
    final ViewTreeObserver observer = view.getViewTreeObserver();
    observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
                view.getViewTreeObserver()
                        .removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            } else view.getViewTreeObserver()
                    .removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            try {
                method.call();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onGlobalLayout " + e.toString());
            }
        }
    });
}

/***
 * Touch listener for changing Thumb Drawable
 *
 * @param v     View Object
 * @param event Motion Event
 * @return
 */
@Override
public boolean onTouch(final View v, final MotionEvent event) {
    if (!lollipopAndAbove())
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                gradientDrawable = new GradientDrawable();
                gradientDrawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.OVAL);
                gradientDrawable.setSize(mOriginalThumbHeight / 2, mOriginalThumbHeight / 2);
                gradientDrawable.setColor(mIsEnabled ? mThumbColor : Color.LTGRAY);
                gradientDrawable.setDither(true);
                gradientDrawable.setAlpha(mThumbAlpha);
                setThumb(gradientDrawable);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                gradientDrawable = new GradientDrawable();
                gradientDrawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.OVAL);
                gradientDrawable.setSize(mOriginalThumbHeight / 3, mOriginalThumbHeight / 3);
                gradientDrawable.setColor(mIsEnabled ? mThumbColor : Color.LTGRAY);
                gradientDrawable.setDither(true);
                gradientDrawable.setAlpha(mThumbAlpha);
                setThumb(gradientDrawable);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    return false;
}


/***
 * Called to substitute getThumb() for APIs below 16
 *
 * @param thumb
 */
@Override
public void setThumb(final Drawable thumb) {
    super.setThumb(thumb);
    mThumb = thumb;
}

/***
 * Sets the thumb alpha (Obviously)
 *
 * @param alpha
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
public void setThumbAlpha(@IntRange(from = 0, to = 255) int alpha) {
    mThumbAlpha = alpha;
    if (!belowJellybean())
        getThumb().setAlpha(mThumbAlpha);
    setLayoutParams(getLayoutParams());
}

/***
 * Enables or disables the whole seekBar!
 *
 * @param enabled
 */
@Override
public void setEnabled(final boolean enabled) {
    mIsEnabled = enabled;
    triggerMethodOnceViewIsDisplayed(this, new Callable<Void>() {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        @Override
        public Void call() throws Exception {
            if (!lollipopAndAbove()) {
                gradientDrawable = new GradientDrawable();
                gradientDrawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.OVAL);
                gradientDrawable.setSize(mOriginalThumbHeight / 3, mOriginalThumbHeight / 3);
                gradientDrawable.setColor(mIsEnabled ? mThumbColor : Color.LTGRAY);
                gradientDrawable.setDither(true);
                gradientDrawable.setAlpha(mThumbAlpha);
                setThumb(gradientDrawable);
                //load up the drawable and apply color
                LayerDrawable ld = (LayerDrawable) getProgressDrawable();
                ScaleDrawable shape = (ScaleDrawable) (ld.findDrawableByLayerId(android.R.id.progress));
                shape.setColorFilter(mIsEnabled ? mProgressColor : Color.LTGRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                //set the background to transparent
                NinePatchDrawable ninePatchDrawable = (NinePatchDrawable) (ld.findDrawableByLayerId(android.R.id.background));
                ninePatchDrawable.setColorFilter(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                //background
                //load up the drawable and apply color
                SeekbarBackgroundDrawable seekBarBackgroundDrawable = new SeekbarBackgroundDrawable(getContext(),
                        mIsEnabled ? mProgressBackgroundColor : Color.LTGRAY, mActualBackgroundColor, getPaddingLeft(), getPaddingRight());
                if (belowJellybean())
                    setBackgroundDrawable(seekBarBackgroundDrawable);
                else
                    setBackground(seekBarBackgroundDrawable);
            }
            CustomSeekBar.super.setEnabled(enabled);
            return null;
        }
    });

}
}
```

Use below methods to change the color's of seekbar:

```
CustomSeekBar mSeekbar =    (CustomSeekBar)findViewById(R.id.video_fragment_seekbar);
mSeekbar.setThumbColor(AppTheme.getInstance(activity).getSeekbarThumbColor());      

 mSeekbar.setProgressColor(AppTheme.getInstance(activity).getColor());           

 mSeekbar.setProgressBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, R.color.seekbar_progress_bg));
```

Comment: Can you tell me why drawable in xml is not working? I am sure it works, but something unexpected is happening.

Comment: Provide **styleable** and  **Drawable**  file too

Answer (score 0):

Put this in progress_drawable.xml:Dont use that

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line">

    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#EDA216"/>
    <corners android:radius="1dp" />

</shape>
```